# Download .torrent from YTS

Tags: download, torrent, httrack

Is it possible to download all torrent files from the yts website? In HHTRACK I get a mirror error, probably caused by the captcha that you need to enter before accessing the site. Is there a way to bypass this or use another method?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do such thing . HHTRACK  won't help U .
If they provides API then there is Possibility to download all torrents at a time.